Using Arel.sql with Arel::Nodes::Case in Ruby for Dynamic subquery
I want to get the timestamp  for a table of locations in each rows' local timezone (stored in tz_name column).
Generalized, how does one have a dynamic sql call for the timestamp in a given timezone  which is stored as a column in a postgres DB table.
Additionally, the time zone for a given location may be null, so a case statement is needed to handle a default timezone.
This query works fine:
locations=Location.select(
        Location.arel_table[:id],
    Arel::Nodes::Case.new
                    .when(
                        Location.arel_table[:tz_name].eq(nil))
                        .then('America/New_York')
                    .else(Location.arel_table[:tz_name]).as("zone") ,
        Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new(
            'date_part',
            [Arel::Nodes.build_quoted('hour'),
            Arel.sql(
                "(select CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE
                        'America/New_York')"

            )
            ]
        ).as("now_hour")
    ).where(
            Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new(
            'date_part',
            [Arel::Nodes.build_quoted('hour'),
            Arel.sql(
                "(select CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE
                        'America/New_York')"

            )
            ]
        ).eq(9)

However, when I try to use the case statement in the Arel.sql call, like so:
 Arel.sql(
                "(select CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE " +
                    Arel::Nodes::Case.new
                    .when(
                        Location.arel_table[:tz_name].eq(nil))
                        .then('America/New_York')
                    .else(Location.arel_table[:tz_name])
                    + ")"

            ) # fails in both cases

or move the Arel.sql into the case statement, like this:
Arel::Nodes::Case.new                                                                           
               .when(                             
                   Location.arel_table[:tz_name].eq(nil))                                  
                   .then(Arel.sql("(select CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE 'America/New_York')"))     #works       
               .else(Arel.sql("(select CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE '#{Location.arel_table[:tz_name]}')"))  #fails

It does not work.
How can I make the call for the timestamp with a Time Zone coming from the table column data ( location.tz_name )?
Solution
As Max suggested below:
Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new(
            'date_part',
            [Arel::Nodes.build_quoted('hour'),
            Arel.sql("(TIMEZONE(COALESCE(locations.tz_name, 'America/New_York'), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP))")
            ]
        ).as("now_hour")


Do you really need a case statement? You could just use TIMEZONE(COALESCE(locations.tz_name, 'America/New_York'), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP). timezone(tz, timestamp) is the function equivilent of AT TIME ZONE and COALESCE returns the first non null argument.

Thanks, that is much more elegant. I will give it a try.

It's somewhat unclear what your end goal is here but I think there is a much easier way to get the same result without the case statement.
location_time = Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new(
  'TIMEZONE', 
  [
    Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new(
      'COALESCE', 
      [
        Location.arel_table[:tz_name], 
        Arel::Nodes.build_quoted('America/New_York')
      ]
    ), 
    Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP",[]) 
  ]
)

If we cast this into SQL we get:
TIMEZONE(COALESCE("locations"."tz_name", 'America/New_York'), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP())


The function timezone(zone, timestamp) is equivalent to the SQL-conforming construct timestamp AT TIME ZONE zone.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html


Altogether we get something like:
class Location < ApplicationRecord

  def self.with_local_time
    select(
      :id,
      tz_name_with_default.as("zone"),
      current_hour.as("now_hour") 
    ).where(
      current_hour.eq(9)
    )
  end

  private

  def self.tz_name_with_default(default: 'America/New_York')
    Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new(
      'COALESCE', 
      [
        Location.arel_table[:tz_name], 
        default
      ]
    )
  end

  def self.time_in_zone(timezone: tz_name_with_default, time: Arel.sql('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'))
    Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new(
      'TIMEZONE', 
      [
        tz_name_with_default, 
        time
      ]
    )
  end

  def self.current_hour
    Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new(
      'DATE_PART',
      [
        Arel::Nodes.build_quoted('hour'),
        time_in_zone
      ]
    )
  end 
end

SELECT 
  "locations"."id", 
  COALESCE("locations"."tz_name", 'America/New_York') AS zone, 
  DATE_PART('hour', TIMEZONE(COALESCE("locations"."tz_name", 'America/New_York'), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP())) AS now_hour 
FROM "locations" 
WHERE 
  DATE_PART('hour', TIMEZONE(COALESCE("locations"."tz_name", 'America/New_York'), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP())) = 9

You can make it a bit less clunky in terms of SQL output by using a subselect in the from clause:
class Location < ApplicationRecord

  def self.with_local_time_2
    select(
      :id, :zone, :now_hour
    )
    .from(
      select(
        :id,
        tz_name_with_default.as("zone"),
        current_hour.as("now_hour") 
      ),
      table_name
    ).where(
      now_hour: 2
    )
  end

   # ...
end

SELECT "locations"."id", "zone", "now_hour" 
FROM 
  (
    SELECT 
      "locations"."id", 
      COALESCE("locations"."tz_name", 'America/New_York') AS zone, 
      DATE_PART('hour', TIMEZONE(COALESCE("locations"."tz_name", 'America/New_York'), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)) AS now_hour 
    FROM "locations"
  ) locations 
WHERE "locations"."now_hour" = $1 
ORDER BY "locations"."id" 
ASC LIMIT $2


Fantastic. Minor suggestions: 1) in the last block substitute :locations with table_name. This way if the table name every changes the code doesn't need to and associations still work accordingly; 2) make the last block a scope with a now_hour argument for idiomatic and flexibility purposes.

@engineersmnky that's a good suggestion. I'll leave refactoring it into scopes as an excercise for the reader through.
